# Filtering Table Cells with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I need help with filtering Table Cells. I can filter the table cells with selecting one value from drop down menu. However when i'm trying to select a date and then search for a value that includes that date it doesn't work.

Current code:

```
       $('#LoggingDatePicker').change(function () {
           //$("#LoggingInputs option:first").attr('selected','selected');
           //$('#LoggingSearch').val('');
            var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
            console.log(value);
            $("table tr").each(function (index) {
                if (!index) return;
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                    var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
                    $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
                    return not_found;
                });
            });
        }); 


        //Displays logging with the specific date


        //Displays logging with the specific logging level which is selected
        $("#LoggingInputs").change(function() {
            //$('#LoggingDatePicker').val('');
            //$('#LoggingSearch').val('');
            var value = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
            $("table tr").each(function (index) {
                if (!index) return;
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).text().toLowerCase().trim();
                    var not_found = (id.indexOf(value) == -1);
                    $(this).closest('tr').toggle(!not_found);
                    return not_found;
                });
            });
        }); 
    });
```

[image]

As shown in the image above I've got the Debug selected and the date selected but it's still showing the '2014-12-18' and '2014-12-19' when it's selected to '2014-12-17'.

How do I filter the values for that specific date and then had a extra search for that date?

Here is a demo for testing: 
[jsfiddle - Test](http://jsfiddle.net/ake8p4xh/)

Comment: Works fine for me after ive replaced the $(this).closest('tr') by $(this).parent('tr'). Could you post a fiddle for better testing?

Comment: `.parent()` on `.closest()` can be suggested only after looking into `html`

Comment: @Ferret This worked, however when you then go to select a different log level and then go back to select Debug. It goes back to the problem i'm having

Comment: we only can guess without a demo. tried to trigger the input-change when selecting a different log level?

Comment: @Ferret i've updated my question and added a link for testing this problem

Comment: @Chris: This will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ttbtp097/

Comment: @abhitalks that helped alot, could you help me adding in a live search as the live search has the same problem and can't search for the value on the specific date

Comment: @Chris: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4jwjkfmt/1/

Comment: @Chris: And this one with free form search added: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4jwjkfmt/4/

Comment: @abhitalks Thankyou for the help, this has worked like a treat.